# R script with list.files function in OneDrive/Sharepoint

Tags: r, onedrive

I have a script that's part of an R Project file that's saved in a folder in OneDrive. One piece of it lists all the .xlsx files in the OneDrive folder like this:

```
file_list <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/MyUsername/My Organization's OneDrive/Folder Creator's Name/Folder Name", pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
```

Others in my organization who have access to the OneDrive folder aren't able to run this line without changing MyUsername to TheirUsername in the filepath. I'd like to make it so that anyone who has access to the OneDrive folder can just open the code and run it without changing things. The working directory should be already specified, because this script lives in a R Project file that's saved in the appropriate folder - how do I set the file path to be the current working directory?

Comment: You just need to map it, use the sync function it creates an alias

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to use [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) here, which anyway is usually the best thing to do when writing scripts that are intended to work for different users on different machines. It might help to provide an example showing the project's file structure to clarify your question.

Comment: Okay yeah I think this should fix it @milanmlft , thanks! I didn't realize "path" was an optional argument and the default was the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative file paths:

```r
file_list <- list.files(path = "<path/relative/to/Rscript/>", pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
```

Another useful option is the [here](https://here.r-lib.org) package. For example:

```r
library(here)
file_list <- list.files(path = here("<folder_with_Excel_files>"), pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
```

This has the added benefit that it should be platform-agnostic.